# Getting Concurrent Modification Exception while update entry of ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, iteration

I'm going to manage received message from server in my android client. For this goal I'm using `ArrayList(HashMap<String, Integer>)` to store arrived messages.

`private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> Notifications = new ArrayList<>();`

Each message has a type and I store that in hash map as a `key` and put qty of that type of message as integer in `HashMAp` too as `value`.

Now I got `CME` when I'm trying to iterate over `ArrayList` to find and update or add new type of arrived messages.

I think, I did it in a right way, where is my fault:

```
    for(HashMap<String, Integer> pack : Notifications) {

        // Searching for Notification Type - If exist update the value
        for(Entry<String, Integer> item : pack.entrySet()){

            String key  = item.getKey();
            if(key.equals(type)){
                Log.e("We find the key here:", key);
                item.setValue(item.getValue()+1);
                found   = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!found){
            ........
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably Using  ConcurrentHashMap should address the problem

Comment: Returns a Set view of the mappings contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation, or through the setValue operation on a map entry returned by the iterator) the results of the iteration are undefined.